# How to find and replace all tabs with spaces in idle

Tags: python, python-idle

I have an invisible `expected an indented block` error, which is likely caused by me using tabs instead of spaces.

When I open the "find/replace" window and try to enter <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the `find` field IDLE unsurprisingly just skips to the `replace` field.

How do I do this?

---

**Final update:**

Thank you for all answers, much appreciated. My problem was that python wants the function comments to be indented too, that is

```
def imdheladumb():
"""
I'm dum as hel
"""
```

does not work, it needs to be

```
def imdheladumb():
    """
    I'm dum as hel
    """
```

Comment: That's the docstring, not the comments, but close enough. IDLE should be strongly suggesting that indentation for you (as in, if you hit Enter and then `"""` after the colon, it ends up properly indented automatically); if it isn't, you may have screwed up your settings somehow…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDLE doesn't let you search to literal tab characters. You can paste one into the search box (as suggested by will), but it will never match anything.

However, it does let you do regular expression searches, and the regular expression `\t` will match a literal tab. So, turn on the `Regular expression` checkbox, and put '`\t` in the `Find:` box, and 4 or 8 spaces (as appropriate) in the `Replace:` box.

But, as will suggested, it's better to use IDLE's features instead of trying to do things manually: Select the block of code with tabbed (or inconsistent) indentation, go to the `Format` menu, and select `Untabify Region`. (Or just hit control-6.) If the tabs were inserted with an editor that uses 4-space tabs, you may need to first use `New Indent Width` and change it to 4, then `Untabify Region`.

IDLE doesn't have any code to guess what your tab size was when you wrote the inconsistent code. The only editor I know of that does is emacs. If you just open the file in emacs, it will try to guess your settings, and then you can select the whole buffer and `untabify-region`. If it guessed right, you're golden; if it guessed wrong, don't save the buffer, because now it'll be even harder to fix. (If you're one of the 3 people in the world who knows how to read emacs lisp but doesn't like emacs, you could look through the `python-mode.el` source and see how it does its magic.)

Comment: All answers appreciated ,this one gets A (ccepted) for effort

Comment: Why does searching for line breaks using regex and \n not work for me? I'll create a separate question.

Comment: Doesn't work in pydroid[Screenshot-2022-09-09-14-07-06-156-ru-iiec-pydroid3.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/gkH72LmH/Screenshot-2022-09-09-14-07-06-156-ru-iiec-pydroid3.jpg) gives [Screenshot-2022-09-09-14-21-12-636-ru-iiec-pydroid3.jpg](https://postimg.cc/ykM1fL12)

Answer (score 3):

A generic way to do this is to just copy a tab character from the document (or just do one in any random text editor and copy it) and then put that into the field.

You could try putting `\t` in there, but that only works in some editors.

Most IDEs have a function to automatically replace tabs with a predefined number of spaces. I suggest turning that on...

EDIT: doing a standard find and replace *could* be dangerous if you're using tabs somewhere else for any reason.

If you look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html), there's an option called "tabify region". That might be more interesting for you.

Comment: Actually, IDLE won't let you search for literal tab characters (well, it will, but they won't match anything). But the tabify functionality in IDLE is probably what the OP actually wants, rather than making search/replace work, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an app for that. ;)

If you enjoy overkill, what about running your code through a regular expression like:

```
re.sub('\t', '\s\s\s\s', yourCode)
```

Comment: I'm assuming finding ninja block indentation errors can't be done simply or else an app would exist for it?

Comment: Awww, but if it's simple, where's the joy?

Comment: Depending on the editor you used, a tab may be 8 spaces instead of 4 (it's 8 in IDLE in tabs mode). Which is why this is difficult. Of course if tabs are used consistently, there's no problem; it doesn't matter whether you do 4 or 8. But unless they're mixed with spaces, the OP wouldn't have gotten any errors in the first place. So you need some smart logic to try to auto-detect the tab settings. The emacs python-mode has code for that, and it usually gets it right (but of course not 100% of the time), so it's possible to do it reasonable well.

Answer (score 0):

For those people having the problem, the new version of VSCode can solve this easily.

1. Click on Tab Sizes at the bottom of the page.
2. Select Convert Indentation to Spaces from the "Select Action" menu that pops up.