# Inconsistent indentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

So I've been making this console text "game" and it seems there's an error that I can't fix. It looks something like this:

```
def left_room3():
    while True:
        i = 0;
        while i &lt len(weapons):
            print "One of your weapons are: " + weapons[i]
            i = i + 1
        yee = raw_input("You have encountered a zombie! What weapon do you use?\n")
        if yee == "sword":
            zombie.health -= sword.damage
            zombie.durability -= 1
            print "The zombie has taken " + str(sword.damage) + " damage."
            me.health -= zombie.damage
            print "You have taken " + str(zombie.damage) + " damage."
        elif yee == "gun":
            zombie.health -= gun.damage
            print "The zombie has taken " + str(gun.damage) + " damage."
            me.health - zombie.damage
            print "You have taken " + str(zombie.damage) + " damage."
            gun.durability -= 1
        else:
            print "That is not an option. Please try again."
        if zombie.health &lt= 0:
            print "You won against the zombie!"
            print "Your save code: 08927672. Enter this at the start to come back to this point."
            room4()
            break
        elif me.health &lt= 0:
            print "You died!"
            exit(0)
```

So it seems to be giving me this error:

```
Error: Inconsistent indentation detected!
1) Your indentation is outright incorrect (easy to fix) OR
2) Your indentation mixes tabs and spaces.
```

I use IDLE, which gives slightly clearer error information.

It highlights this line of code:

```
    i = 0;
```

But I don't know if that's actually the code causing the problem...
(I've seen cases where the IDE/compiler highlights one piece of code, but it's a different piece that's causing the problem)

I also have other blocks of code almost exactly like this, but IDLE doesn't highlight them (maybe because it checks that block first?  I don't know, but it sounds pretty wrong to me that IDLE would check from bottom to top (because code runs top to bottom), but it could be possible.)

Comment: I'd always check the line above and below the one it's flagged.

Comment: You don't need the semicolon here:  `i = 0;`

Comment: @Brosta you don't need a semicolon anywhere

Comment: @Aaron That's the only place it's used in his code, but I should have clarified since the OP stated he is newer to programming. I edited my comment above

Comment: regarding tabs and spaces... you can only use one or the other and it's conventional to only use spaces (4 of them per level of indentation to be exact)

Comment: Don't listen to @Aaron. Tabs are better than spaces! But seriously, just use one or the other (use tabs). This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691790/how-to-find-and-replace-all-tabs-with-spaces-in-idle

Comment: @chasmani I like how the question you referenced was asking how to eliminate all tabs from their life... (and further illustrates why they can often be a pain)

Comment: wait, why do i have a *semicolon* there?

Comment: still doesn't work without a colon... :(

Comment: If you have another editor on hand (notepad++, pycharm?) turn on the visibility of whitespaces and tabs. It will be easier to spot.

Comment: Oh, and by the way @chasmani

Comment: i use TABS ONLY...

Comment: ok @silent... i'll try... i guess i'll just reinstall notepad++ XD

Comment: @Flameteor my tabby brethren. If you have Sublime Text you can just select all, then View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation To Tabs

Comment: what the hell... it was an indentation error... im SOOO dumb XD

Comment: well i guess i wrote all that for nothing... thanks to you all tho! Im stupid...

Comment: @Flameteor if you're using npp, as of version 7.3.3 the view tabs menu item is under: `View -> Show Symbol -> Show White Space and TAB`

Comment: o wait, it was not an indentation error... wut?

Comment: okkkkk... yeah, im still not sure what this is then...

Answer (score 1):

The `error` that you are getting strongly suggests that you are mixing `spaces` and `tabs`. In most other programming languages, indentation will **not** effect how the `code` runs, merely make it easier to follow.

This is different in Python where all `scopes` (I think that is the right terminology) so `if-statements`, `loops`, etc. are defined by the line's indentation level.

As a result of this, you need to be *consistent* throughout your entire code on what type of indentation you are using - so `1` tab, `4` spaces or whatever **and stick to it!** Otherwise, the compiler won't know which `scope` that line is in and when you have exited that section.

It is very hard to see what line exactly you have made a mistake in from your question's code sniped, but this is most likely what is causing the problem so you should take a closer look at your actual code.

If you can't find it by looking, most text-editors have the option to `'highlight / show white-space and tab'` and this will make the source of the error stand out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually, it seems that even though i corrected myself multiple times in the formatting of **tabs only**, i cant get this to work... besides, for some reason, in IDLE, it messes up my whitespacing so i have to fix it before trying to run it again (which, as stated before, the code doesn't work), soooooo yeah... thanks for trying though ;)